# Getting "No module named sklearn.model_selection" in C# (IronPython)

Tags: python, c#, ironpython

Trying to run the following code from C# (IronPython)

I am getting the following error:

> "No module named sklearn.model_selection"
> from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

```
class TestPy:
    def traintestsplit(X, y):
        print("entered method")
        trainX, testX, trainy, testy = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=2)

        return trainX, testX, trainy, testy
```

What is the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean with "unable to run"?

Comment: How do you try to run this code?

Comment: 1st line of the code is throwing error i.e sklearn import statement. How to use it in IronPython?

Comment: Giving this error while executing the above code from IronPython: 'No module named sklearn.model_selection'